# Working with SSL certificates with .Net Framework

Tags: c#, ssl, get, yandex

I try to make GET request to Yandex service speech recognize engine- to get stream recognize:

```
GET /asr_partial HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent:Ross' Third apartmentAliveClient\r\n
Host: voice-stream.voicetech.yandex.net:80\r\n
Upgrade: dictation\r\n\r\n
```

So, I write simple code to do that:

```
public string HttpGet(String serviceUri, String host, String userAgent, String upgradeValue)
    {
     req = WebRequest.Create(serviceUri)
                    as HttpWebRequest;

        req.ClientCertificates.Add(_certificat);

        req.Host = host;
        req.UserAgent = userAgent;
        req.Date = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(req.ToString());
        req.Headers["Upgrade"] = upgradeValue;
        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
                                      as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But when I call method- catch exception:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

OK, I think that this problem is that I should import CA certificat of  ( [Yandex site](https://tech.yandex.ru/speechkit/cloud/doc/dg/concepts/speechkit-dg-recogn-docpage/#stream) to my machine.
So, i try to do that- find some CA -but -Certum,Certum Level 4 CA, but as i understand- it is now that what i need.

OK, I write that code to get certificate and store it to file:

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(customXertificateValidation);

private bool customXertificateValidation(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors error)
    {
        if (cert.Subject == "CN=*.asr.yandex.net, O=YANDEX, OU=ITO, L=Moscow, S=Russia, C=RU")
        {
            var certBytes= cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
            File.WriteAllBytes("yandexCA.txt", certBytes);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then, I modified method, import certificate and add it to request:

```
 public string HttpGet(String serviceUri, String host, String userAgent, String upgradeValue)
    {          
        _certificat = new X509Certificate2();

        var certBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("yandexCA.txt");            
        _certificat.Import(certBytes);           

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(serviceUri)
                    as HttpWebRequest;

        req.ClientCertificates.Add(_certificat);

        req.Host = host;
        req.UserAgent = userAgent;
        req.Date = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(req.ToString());
        req.Headers["Upgrade"] = upgradeValue;
        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
                                      as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Certificate Subject:

```
Subject = "CN=*.asr.yandex.net, O=YANDEX, OU=ITO, L=Moscow, S=Russia, C=RU"
```

But the error is same:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

What I should do to fix that error?
Do I need to install this certificate to my machine? If yes- How to do that?- I got only array of bytes.

P.S. At the code I use callback:

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(customXertificateValidation);
```

So, the response is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: remote server send message: (501) not supported.